# Create and set custom keyboard layout

Tags: xorg, keyboard, keyboard-layout, xkb

I want to create and set a custom keyboard layout with setxkbmap. I created a file in `~/.xkb/prog` with this content:

```
partial default alphanumeric_keys
xkb_symbols "basic" {

include "latin(type4)"

name[Group1]="es for developers";

key <AE01> {[           1,           exclam,    exclamdown,          bar   ]};    
key <AD03> {[           e,                E,      EuroSign,     sterling   ]};
key <AB06> {[           n,                N,        ntilde,       Ntilde   ]};    
key <AB07> {[           m,                M,            mu,           mu   ]};    
key <AB10> {[       slash,         question,  questiondown,    dead_hook   ]};

include "level3(ralt_switch)"
};
```

And I tried to load it with `setxkbmap -I$HOME/.xkb "prog"`, but I get a 'Error loading new keyboard description'

I also tried it with `setxkbmap -I$HOME/.xkb "prog" -print | xkbcomp -I$HOME/.xkb - $DISPLAY`, but I get this error: 'Can't find file "prog" for symbols include'

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try that last one, i.e.:

```
% setxkbmap prog -print | xkbcomp -I$HOME/.xkb - $DISPLAY
```

But put your layout in `~/.xkb/symbols/prog` (note the **symbols** subdirectory).

Comment: Hello @angus, could you look at my question please? Maybe you know better https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/414589/beginner-friendly-debian-package-for-custom-keyboard-layout

Comment: You don't need the first include: your command will not change the `setxkbmap` settings, just xkbcomp: If you try `setxkbmap -print` after that, you will not see the modifications you just did.