# Beginner friendly Debian package for custom keyboard layout?

Tags: debian, software-installation, gnome, xkb

I have a custom keyboard layout that I want to install like this:

`$sudo apt install my-custom-kbd-layout`

Is this possible with Debian?

Because I started writing some python script to automate the manual steps, but maybe I'm over complicating things. Is there a better way?

Edit: removed code

Comment: This looks like a code-review question.

Comment: The code is for reference here, not for reviewing.

Comment: I don’t know much about package control, but If guess you could do 2 things, assuming it is not the code that is the problem. 1) push this to an official/unofficial repository (make sure it is added to the repo list) and download it with `apt`, or 2) since it is Python, maybe you can reserve a PIP package specifically for this.

Comment: I'm not sure if my approach is appropriate at all, because here https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/55933/create-and-set-custom-keyboard-layout?rq=1 they use `setxkbmap` to add the keyboard layout at runtime as an "addon" instead of modifying the system files manually as I do. But using `setxkbmap` may be too difficult for a beginner and I don't want to make installing this keyboard layout difficult. I want to script the installation and make it as easy as installing a package. I don't care if it's a package or not but this looks easiest to me, for now.

Comment: I believe it is quite easy from the start, as (at least Ubuntu does, I think Debian follows suit) you are queried of what keyboard to use via arrow keys or mouse. Otherwise, you may be able to make a shell script that DOES modify settings for the wanted keyboard layout. While I see this as making the code less legible for beginning users, I don’t believe it’ll be a problem. I’d take this to a private convo, but I’m on mobile right now.

Comment: Forget the code please, it's just here for people to understand what I'm trying to do. The users (or "beginners" as I called them) should not see any code, they should just run `apt install my-kbd-layout` and it will be there. Or maybe I should use `setxkbmap` or another approach if somebody knows better. Your 1) "push to repo" is a possibility. But the Debian people would have to accept it. And modifying system files might be bad. I should ask this on a Debian mailing list maybe, but I thought I would ask here before.

Comment: I'd recommend you see how the package `keyboards-rg` does it (`apt-get source keyboards-rg`) and copy it.

Comment: Thank you @angus, if you would write this as an answer I'll accept it. I will try to copy this package and adapt to my needs, and see how far I can go with it.

Comment: possible, yes.  beginner friendly, no.  ... i went into a brief discussion of one possible solution [on a similar question on askubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/a/901356/669043).  you might not want to submit your customizations to the official package, but could use that to make your own patch for a local build of `xkb-data` that includes your changes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Package `keyboards-rg` provides several keyboard layouts aimed at Eastern European users. By examining its source (retrieve it with `apt-get source keyboards-rg`) you can see what files you need to provide, what to put in the `debian/` directory, etc.

Comment: I'll put the url to source in case someone else is interested https://packages.debian.org/stretch/keyboards-rg

Comment: For other people who want to make a keyboard package, I found this excellent answer here https://superuser.com/a/1168603, which confirms what I hoped would not be. Because I use Gnome, I can't avoid editing the `evdev.lst` and `evdev.xml` files. Why is this a problem? Because system updates will overwrite my change. The other problem is that I have to write a script to insert the snippets for my custom keyboard at the right place, without deleting other custom edits or breaking something. Very complicated, I was hoping a "plugin" style architecture was possible.

Comment: There is another problem with the `setxkbmap` aproach, it completely overrides my Gnome settings. So if I have `de` activated in Gnome and then do `setxkbmap xy`, `xy` will be active in every window or terminal but Gnome still shows `de` as active. Switching keyboards in Gnome with `Win + Space` I can see the keyboard symbols switching but actually nothing happens; I expected it would override the `setxkbmap xy` command.

Comment: @aliopi Once you manage to do it, please write a better answer and assign it to you. It'll be an asset for the site.

Comment: I think this task is too difficult for my experience level with Debian / Linux. But I gathered a lot of information with this question, so many thanks to everyone and apologies.

Comment: @aliopi the answer you link mentions disabling gnome's settings daemon if you prefer the `setxkbmap` approach.  you do need to understand `setxkbmap` needs all the layouts you want:  you'll need `setxkbmap -layout de,xy` to get both layouts.  on the other hand, if you make changes to the system files correctly you'll be able to use gnome's builtin handling.